# Unison command not found

Tags: homebrew, unison

Recently my [Unison](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) application has stopped working on my Mac terminal saying the command cannot be found. Not sure if this was the reason but I recently reinstalled brew (which is how it was installed), which may have broken it.

Here is the error output:

```
mac:~ Imran$ unison sites
-bash: unison: command not found
```

I can see that if I `locate unison` unison is found in the following directories:

```
> /Users/Imran/unison.log /Users/Imran/unison.tar.gz
> /usr/local/Cellar/unison /usr/local/Cellar/unison/2.40.102
> /usr/local/Cellar/unison/2.40.102/COPYING
> /usr/local/Cellar/unison/2.40.102/INSTALL_RECEIPT.json
> /usr/local/Cellar/unison/2.40.102/NEWS
> /usr/local/Cellar/unison/2.40.102/README
> /usr/local/Cellar/unison/2.40.102/TODO.txt
> /usr/local/Cellar/unison/2.40.102/bin
> /usr/local/Cellar/unison/2.40.102/bin/unison
> /usr/local/Library/Formula/unison.rb
> /usr/local/Library/LinkedKegs/unison /usr/local/bin/unison
> /usr/local/opt/unison /usr/share/zsh/5.3/functions/_unison
```

Can someone help me get this working again? I suspect its something to do with the link to the app being broken.

Comment: Care to share the error output?

Comment: Updated my original post to include the original command and error

Comment: What output does _which unison_ give you?

Comment: Literally returns nothing

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue when trying to use Unison from Windows to Mac (where it has been installed with Brew).

You can give an explicit path for the unison executable on the server by using the command-line option

> -servercmd /full/path/name/of/unison

or adding

> servercmd=/full/path/name/of/unison

to your profile

[Source](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ebcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html)

Comment: This is the only thing that finally worked.

Answer (score 2):

If you've done a reinstall of a brew cask, you may need to manually link it again if it can't be found on your path

```
brew link unison
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone running into this error on macOS:
If you're using `zsh` (or running a newer macOS version where `zsh` is the default) you have to modify or create `~/.zshenv`.

Add your path to the shell environment by adding one of the following snippets to `~/.zshenv`.

For ARM64 (M1 Macs):

```sh
eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)
```

or on x86 (Intel Macs)

```sh
eval $(/usr/local/bin/brew shellenv)
```

or you simply source your `zshrc`:

```sh
source ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://alliance.seas.upenn.edu/%7Ebcpierce/wiki/index.php?n=Main.UnisonFAQTroubleshooting) the error message `bash: unison: command not found` means:

> Make sure Unison is installed on the host you are trying to connect to.

Answer (score -2):

Your user's *PATH* variable does not include a link to the *unison* binary.

Add /usr/local/Cellar/unison/2.40.102/bin/unison to your .bashrc,

```
$ vi ~/.bashrc
```

add the following,

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/unison/2.40.102/bin/unison
```

save and quit, and then re-read your users bashrc file,

```
exec bash
```

Now try *which unison* again, or actually just try running it with,

```
$ unison
```

Comment: Just tried these steps, no effect seems to have taken place. Running `which unison` still returns nothing.

Comment: What does _echo $PATH_ return?

Comment: I think the point of **homebrew** is that it creates symbolic links in `/usr/local/bin` which you are supposed to use so you don’t have to change your scripts when you install newer versions and so you don’t have to include the path to every single package in your PATH - you just add `/usr/local/bin` to your PATH and you are all set to go...